# downloadProgress and finished signals not being emitted?

Tags: c++, qt

I have in place what I think is the right code in order to handle download from my webapp, though for some reason the downloadProgress and finished signals aren't being emitted and the relevant slots are not being called?

**UPDATE:** I added `reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url);` but I'm not sure how to get the request URL as it's not a stadard URL it's just a "#" as PHP generated the file?

```
void MainWindow::unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply *reply) {

    qDebug() << "Left click - download!";
    qDebug() << "Bytes to download: " << reply->bytesAvailable();

    QString str = reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");

    QString end = str.mid(21);
    end.chop(1);

    qDebug() << "File name: " << end;
    qDebug() << "File type: " << reply->rawHeader("Content-Type");
    qDebug() << "File size (bytes): " << reply->bytesAvailable();
    QString defaultFileName = QFileInfo(end).fileName();
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"), defaultFileName);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if(!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Downloader",
            tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
            .arg(fileName).arg(file->errorString()));
        delete file;
        file = NULL;
        return;
    }

    downloadRequestAborted = false;

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished()));
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(downloadReadyRead()));
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
        connect(progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(cancelDownload()));
        progressDialog->setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1...").arg(fileName));
        //downloadButton->setEnabled(false);
        progressDialog->exec();


    //QFile file(fileName);
    //file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );
    //file.write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
    //file.close();
}

void MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug() << bytesReceived << bytesTotal;
    if(downloadRequestAborted)
        return;
    progressDialog->setMaximum(bytesTotal);
    progressDialog->setValue(bytesReceived);
}

void MainWindow::downloadReadyRead()
{
    if(file)
        file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
}

void MainWindow::downloadFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Download finished!";
    if(downloadRequestAborted)
    {
        if(file)
        {
            file->close();
            file->remove();
            delete file;
            file = NULL;
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
        progressDialog->hide();
        //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
        return;
    }

    downloadReadyRead();
    progressDialog->hide();
    //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
    file->flush();
    file->close();

    if(reply->error())
    {
        //Download failed
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Download failed", tr("Failed: %1").arg(reply->errorString()));
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = NULL;
    delete file;
    file = NULL;
}

void MainWindow::cancelDownload()
{
    downloadRequestAborted = true;
    reply->abort();
    progressDialog->hide();
    //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: cut this down the least amount of code necessary to exhibit the problem